# NetBeans 7.1.1 and CodeIgniter 2.1.2 autocompletion not working :/

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete, codeigniter-2, netbeans-7.1

Okay for some reason I cannot get the CI autocompletion to work on NetBeans for the life of me. For example when I type in `ci_control` in the netbeans ide I get the code hint for `CI_Controller ci_auto_complete.php` while it is pointing towards the correct file, it fails to correctly auto complete and leaves me with `CI_Controller::get_instance()`  after I click enter. 
I have codeIgniter successfully installed, because I can run applications correctly, I just have trouble getting the autocompletion to work.

I even tried plugging in some code in the system ->core ->model and controller files as explained in this tutorial, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzvSA0hq3Ts  to no avail.

I would appreciate it if somebody can please help me!

Thanks in advance,

NetBeans 7.1.1
CodeIgniter 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have configured the Netbeans (7.1.1) for Codeigniter, as suggested in the following link. It does auto completion for me.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/187949/